# error using container-filter in ComboBox field

Tags: xml, filter, combobox, containers, vaadin7

Using vaadin 7. Trying to do filtering. There is the error:
vaadin.data.util.filter.generator.exception.MissingRequiredAttributeException: Required attribute value is null or missing.

There is the filter:

```
<container-filter>
    <if testExpr="not editNew or currentFacilityTreeIndexProperty.getValue() != null">
        <not>
            <like property="facilityTreeIndex" valueExpr="currentFacilityTreeIndexProperty.getValue()"
                                        onlyMatchPrefix="true" />
        </not>
    </if>
</container-filter>
```

What is an attribute of a filter and what is missing? Other filters used in the same file for other ComboBoxFields have no attributes(if i get it right what attributes are):
`<container-filter>`

Comment: Vaadin's API is not based on this kind of xml's. So you must be using some meta framework build on top of Vaadin. What is it? Do you know author of it?

Comment: Yes, he is my mentor) So this is the internal error? I can't find it on google.

Comment: Very likely. It looks like some kind of xml to java unmarshalling issue. You won't find anything about this outside of your organisation.